# Manipulating a global static variable

Tags: c++, variables, static, global-variables

Suppose I have `main.cpp`, `file.h` and `file.cpp`. Where `file.cpp` implements all the prototypes in `file.h` and `main.cpp` includes `file.h`.

Very simple structure. I was wondering If i declared a static global variable in `main.cpp` would it be possible to access to such variable when implementing all the functions in `file.cpp`? With a quick attempt this doesn't seem to be case... I can't even compile it.

But would it be possible to work this around?

Just to clarify I have

file.h:

```
#ifndef __FILE_H
#define __FILE_H
#include <iostream>

void my_func();

#endif
```

file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"

using namespace std;

void my_func() {
    //do something with my_static_var
}
```

and main.cpp

```
#include "file.h"

static int my_var = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    my_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Assume no classes involved

Comment: Why is the variable static if you need to access it from another translation unit?

Comment: `static int my_var = 0;` makes the variable hidden from any other translation units. And don't use global variables anyways please, that's just indicating serious design flaws and lack of good software design knowledge. _"Assume no classes involved"_ Why????????????

Comment: You can access a static variable of one translation unit inside another. This is allowed. But to get a reference to it the only option is to declare a non static function in the header file: `int& get_my_var()` and then define it in main.cpp `int& get_my_var(){return my_var;}`. Such a convolution would be unusefull, declaring my_var with linkage would be more appropriate. Are you looking for a way to make a symbol hidden?

Comment: @Oliv _"You can access a static variable of one translation unit inside another"_ Do not confuse _global_ and `static` variables (out of class context). Using `static` hides a global variable definition  from any other TU, just like a _anonymous namespace_ would do.

Comment: I would never use global variables unless strictly necessary...it's just something I came across and I'd like to know if that's possible. Something like this was on a test (it was actually a static array of fixed size). It was a main with such static array, I wasn't allow to modify the main at all. And I had to write the solution in a `.cpp`, and I was wondering how to access to variables/array declared in such a way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are confused by the term access. Access means accessing the value. static variable have no linkage and what is hidden is their name (the symbol in object file parlance)

Comment: @Oliv So how would you realize the `void my_func() {
    //do something with my_static_var
}` in this scenario? I may be _dazed_, but certainly not _confused_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See my previous comment, you define a function with linkage in main that return a reference to my_static_var and then you declare this function in file.cpp (but as I said this is an unnecessary convolution).

Comment: @Oliv So you proposed to move the definition of `my_func()` to `main.cpp`? Fine. But doesn't really answer the question (TBF that's why it's a comment instead of an answer maybe).

Comment: @user8469759 Can you modify one of the header file included by main?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I suppose it is a real problem and the question has not established all the constraints so I am digging.

Comment: @Oliv Well the actual code had only two `.cpp`s. The main had a static variable/array as I said, but it also had all the functions supposed to be implemented declared as `extern` still in the main. Such file couldn't be modified at all. The solution had to be written in a different `.cpp`. This was the actual setting, if I remember correctly, I've just tried to reproduce that case.

Comment: @user8469759 If you're sure you want that, just drop the `static` keyword to allow external linkage.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I cannot drop that keyword...

Comment: @user8469759 You could compile main.cpp and try to guess by analysing the object file where will be located the array in the executable, you could use linker command to help you in doing that. But even if you succeeded in doing this, and were able to access the storage associated to this static variable, then you should know that the compiler has certainly performed many optimization based on the assumption that the static variable will not be accessed from outside the main.cpp translation unit, so in the end, you would probably see trash.

Comment: @user8469759 In that case you'll need to leave `my_func()` within the same TU. No other way to access that variable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ @Oliv, what about declaring the functions in the main as `extern`? Can this help?

Comment: @user8469759 No `extern` won't help. As mentioned in my 1st comment, `my_static_var ` is strictly hidden for linkage from any other TU's as long there's the `static` keyword.

Comment: @user8469759 `my_func` is already "extern", so you can modify `file.h` and recompile main.cpp? If that is the case there is just no problem!

Comment: @Oliv, please elaborate.

Comment: @user8469759 Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224679/c-static-keyword-vs-c-private-scope) please.

Comment: Inside the header file you define a zone guarded by a `#if PROVIDE_MY_FUNC#` where you define my_func and forward declare the static array. Then you define PROVIDE_MY_FUNC when compiling main.cpp but not when compiling file.cpp! This would be as if you had modified main.cpp

Comment: @Oliv, could you please provide an example? So I can use it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

A variable with **internal linkage** can be referred to only from scopes within its translation unit (which typically means its source file). A variable declared with the `static` keyword has internal linkage.

A variable with **external linkage** can be referred to from other translation units (other source files). A variable has external linkage if it is not in an anonymous namespace and:

- it is declared with the `extern` keyword, or
- it is namescape-scope (such as `my_var` in the question) and is declared with neither `const` nor `static` (unlike `my_var` in the question).

Reference: [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage)

Answer (score 1):

No. The `static` here literally means "don't let me do" what you're trying to do. It makes the object private to that translation unit, with *internal linkage*.

Remove the `static` and you'll be golden (use an `extern` declaration elsewhere to bring it into scope), though you should consider avoiding globals.