# Why `static` functions in different TUs do not break the ODR?

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, linkage, one-definition-rule

The ODR allows us to define several times the same inline function (with some restrictions).

However, what about the simpler case of `static` functions?

```
// First TU
static int foo() { return 0; }
int bar1() { return foo(); }

// Second TU
static int foo() { return 1; }
int bar2() { return foo(); }
```

If we do a quick read of [basic.def.odr]p4, we could naively conclude that this would be UB:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement (9.4.1); no diagnostic required.

Where in the C++ standard is specified that each `foo` is a different function and therefore not breaking the ODR, even if they have the same name?

Is it simply a matter of reading [basic.link]p2.2 (i.e. due to internal linkage the names do not refer to the same entity and therefore [basic.def.odr]p4 does not apply here)? Or are there more nuances/rules involved to make this determination (like something in [basic.scope])?

Note that, with unnamed namespaces, the outcome is clear, because the name would be already different/unique.

Comment: ***due to internal linkage the names do not refer to the same entity and therefore  odr does not apply here*** Exactly right.

Comment: _@Acorn_ Sorry, I've overlooked the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No problem! :) Tell us about the bug! Linking-related ones always hurt a lot...

Comment: @Acorn We expected a specific behavior, that didn't happen, because the TU local function was defined without the `static` specifier, and the linker took on the first definition found from another TU, that was added later to the project :). I've even posted a not so well received [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224679/c-static-keyword-vs-c-private-scope) after we found out.

Answer (score 6):

Correct — even though they have the same name locally, those are two different functions/entities, so there's no violation.

> [`[basic.link]/4.3:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4.3) When a name has *internal linkage*, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation unit.
>
> [`[basic.link]/5:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#5) A name having namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of a variable, variable template, function, or function template that is explicitly declared `static`; or *[..]*

I can't immediately find any further wording (normative or otherwise) that applies, but I don't think we need any.

Comment: @Brian Actually that looks like the missing piece!

Comment: Id' say [`[basic.link]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11) is what OP wants.