# Shouldn't using functions from an anonymous namespace or static functions from another file give an error?

Tags: c++, linker

So, say in file `F1.cpp` I have functions `fun1` and `fun2`, with `fun1` belonging to an anonymous namespace also `fun2` makes a call to `fun1`. Now in my file `F2.cpp` I include `F1.h` which only has a signature for `fun2`, in `F2.cpp` I then make a call to `fun2`. I get no errors and the output is correct, but considering `fun2` calls `fun1` which is an anonymous namespace shouldn't I get an error?

For example:

**F1.h**

```
#ifndef F1_H
#define F1_H

// A function declaration
float fun2();

#endif
```

**F1.cpp**

```
#include "F1.h"

// Anonymous namespace
namespace {
    float fun1()
    {
        return 3.5f;
    }
}

// Function that was declared in the header
float fun2() {
    return fun1();
}
```

**F2.cpp**

```
#include "F1.h"

int main()
{
    return static_cast<int>(fun2());
}
```

Compiling these files together and then running gives no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code instead of describing it. Please [edit] your post to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that the `static` keyword would only hide code from files compiled for c-linkage. You also can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224679/c-static-keyword-vs-c-private-scope)

Comment: Please check freshly added code.

Comment: The identifiers in your code do not match the ones in your text. Please change your code to match your description of the code. Also, why does your *minimal* example define a `struct`? There is no mention of a `struct` in your text.

Comment: @Legolas `float dist(point a, point b)` is explicitely exported from your module and can legally call `float distance(point a, point b)` from your anonymous namespace. I don't see why you would expect a linker error for this case.

Comment: As for your actual question, why would you expect an error when `fun2` calls `fun1`?

Comment: Why should it raise an error ? `dist()` is well-known. `distance()` is only used inside the `dist()` definition. When the linker tries to link `dist()` with its definition, it will find it in _mylib.cpp_ and when it'll encounter the call to `distance()`, there will be no problem because the `distance()` definition was already encountered above. You just have created a file-private function. `distance()` is private in _mylib.cpp_ and can be **used only here**. This is what you did, so it's fine. (I answered here because the question is still on-hold)

Comment: @JaMiT It says example.

Comment: @Fareanor my question is how are we able to utilize a file private function from another file.

Comment: In fact, you didn't. In another file, you only used `dist()` not `distance()` which is fine. `distance()` is only called inside the `dist()` definition which is located in the same file than `distance()` definition. To be more clear, `distance()` is private to _mylib.cpp_ so you can call it only here. As you never called it outside, it works fine.

Comment: This being said, your function is file-private because it is not declared in any header. The anonymous namespace is only preventing you from breaking the one-definition-rule (if somewhere else you defined a function with the same name) by linking it internally to its translation unit.

Comment: @Legolas Yes, it does say "example". Sorry, but I fail to see what point you are trying to make. Is it that I should have requested "Please change your *example* code to match your description of the code" instead of leaving out the word "example"?

Comment: @JaMiT what I'm saying is that it's perfectly fine to give an example of the situation I described using different file names, albeit I get why you'd like it to be that way.

Comment: @Legolas I disagree with "perfectly". It is fine/allowable, but not perfectly fine. Case in point: when I read the first paragraph of your question I knew what you were talking about. Then I read the code you presented as an example, and I doubted myself. It wasn't until I you accepted an answer that I felt confident that my initial reading was correct. This is not a situation to describe as "perfect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> considering fun2 calls fun1 which is an anonymous namespace shouldn't I get an error?

No.

The `fun1` being in anonymous namespace means that it is usable (can be called) by any code inside `F1.cpp`, and not usable by any other code.

Since `fun2` -- the user of `fun1` *is* in `F1.cpp`, there is no problem with `fun2` calling `fun1`.

The `fun1` being in anonymous namespace places *absolutely no* restrictions on where `fun2` can be used.